# Isotope masonry unexpected behavior

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I'm stumbling many hours with the problem below, can someone help me with that please ?

This is a little part of my new parallax website:

http://bit.ly/1mA3wiq

When you click on 'Read more', the selected blogitem should expand. The other blogitems should be arround it. (Masonry effect) (Isotope)

**My problem**

When you click the read more button at 'Blog 1' all the other blog items go under it... but it should position arround it. Like 'Blog 2' and 'Blog 3' etc..

Does anybody know WHY this happens? I tried many things... even another library and clearing up my code..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

fix this issue then  change  readmore href to # only test it

thats work correcetly after click read more but your size of box not good for isotope library to handle position to page !

i had this problem later u most be get the avrage ratio per item to get best view